# use annotation click when button is created in onCreate

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-annotations

I want to add the @Click Android Annotation to button which is not defined in the layout.xml, but created in onCreate and added programmatically to a SearchView:

```
@EActivity
public class NewRecipeActivity extends BaseActivity{

  @ViewById(R.id.buttonLoadExtra)
   Button buttonLoadExtra;

  @ViewById(R.id.listViewSearch)
   ListView listViewSearch;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_newrecipe);

    buttonLoadExtra =  new Button(this);
    buttonLoadExtra.setId(R.id.buttonLoadExtra);
    buttonLoadExtra.setText("Weitere Laden...");


    listViewSearch.addFooterView(buttonLoadExtra);
 } 
 @Click
  void buttonLoadExtra(){ //Do stuff }
  }
```

Where the id buttonLoadExtra is defined in a resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <item name="buttonLoadExtra" type="id" />
</resources>
```

But it does not work like this. This might be obvious, because the button does not already exist, when linking to the click action is done. So is there a way to solve this or can i use the annotation just for an "existing button".

Thank you in advance

Comment: are you talking about @Click(R.id.buttonId)  anotation on button click method buttonLoadExtra?

Comment: yes, the on click wont get fired. no matter if @Click(R.id.buttonLoadExtra) or just @Click

Comment: have you declared onClick attribute in Layout XML then remove it.

Comment: i do not have this button declared in my layout, because if i do, the addFooter-Method fails. so the button actually does not exist till i create it in oncreate, thats my dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `@Click` annotation is not working if you are adding the view later, because AndroidAnnotation is setting the listener during `setContentView()`, and you are adding the view after that runs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I guessed that and in the end solved it with a viewholder :)